# How to extract Network Request Header info from page

Tags: node.js, http-headers, nightwatch.js

I'm using nodejs and nightwatchjs to run my test scripts.

I need to devise a test script that will check that a certain piece of information is displayed in the header of a webpage.

Below I have highlighted the information that I need to extract.

Once I've extracted this info, I will then test that a certain value is contained within this 'Headers' information (gpi=UID for example).

[image]

Are there any specific nodejs modules that could extract this information?

I've read [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package info, but couldn't find a way of extracting the info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NightwatchJS API testing plugin](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-plugin-apitesting) so that you can then write a test to do `expect` against the headers

```js
it('demo test async', async function({supertest}) {
    await supertest
      .request(`https://myUrl.com`)
      .get('<insert the path you want to test here e.g. / >')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/);
  });
```

The plugin page has a lot more details on it and you can always ask in their [discord](https://discord.gg/ZZ3ZJVFAZb)

Answer (score 0):

It looked like cookies is highlighted in your screenshot? If that is what you are after try this method off the browser object https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getCookie.html#apimethod-container